# Render colored text to a ncurses window in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, python-curses

Is it possible to/how do I rendered pre-terminal-formatted colored text to a `curses.window` in python?

Basically, I'm trying to add some simple curses-based UI stuff on top of an existing console application that already renders colored log output, which I'm trying to redirect into a curses `window`.

However, it seems like curses somehow turns off the various control codes that control color.

Here's a minimal script, using `colorama` for a stand-in for the text-source:

```
import colorama
import curses

def run_gui():
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()

    stdscr.insertln()
    stdscr.insertln()
    stdscr.insstr(colorama.Fore.RED+'wattt'+colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    stdscr.insertln()
    stdscr.insstr(colorama.Fore.GREEN+'wattt'+colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    stdscr.insertln()
    stdscr.insstr(colorama.Fore.YELLOW+'wattt'+colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    stdscr.insertln()
    stdscr.refresh()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    run_gui()
```

This renders:

```
^[[33mwattt^[[0m
^[[32mwattt^[[0m
^[[31mwattt^[[0m
```

Is there a way I can just tell curses to allow the normal control codes, or am I going to have to rework all the existing color functionality?

Answer (score 0):

short: The latter ("rework").

long:

The "normal control codes" happen to be device-dependent; curses provides a device-independent interface to terminals.  Quoting from the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html):

> The  ncurses  library  routines  give  the  user a terminal-independent
>   method of updating  character  screens  with  reasonable  optimization.

Actually most curses implementations provide a low-level interface via [terminfo-based functions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) which let you do special tweaks, but

- Python's binding doesn't include that (it covers only a part of ncurses), and
- for the sort of thing suggested, it would not be useful, since it is manipulating information that curses is designed to know how to manage more efficiently than your program would do.  Preventing it from knowing what's on the screen would interfere with what curses does.

The Python documentation mentions *attributes*, e.g., in [`window.insstr(`*str[*`,` *attr]*`)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.insstr)

your example could do something like

```
stdscr.insstr("wattt", COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_RED))
```

What you're asking about has been asked before.  For example:

- [*`How to interpret ansi escape code like "\033[; 1; 31mHello World\033[0m"`*](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2008-11/msg00026.html)
- [Curses for python. Convert ansi color codes from stdin to curses output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877851/curses-for-python-convert-ansi-color-codes-from-stdin-to-curses-output)
- [How to create scrollable console application that support ANSI escape code sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368796/how-to-create-scrollable-console-application-that-support-ansi-escape-code-seque)

Comment: The input is coming via a SSH pipe, and it's coloring is much more complex then the example. I really don't want to have to try to parse the input coloring, just to reconstruct it.